# cannot ssh into my github codespaces using github cli

Tags: github, github-cli

whenever I try to access my codespace using ssh like this: `gh codespaces ssh` then select a codespace. I'm always getting this error:
`Load key "~/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied`
and then prompt for a password which isn't anything I have set.
the codespace works fine in the browser.

the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` exists and it has `600` permissions.

some info that I think might be useful:

1. I tested with a codespace created in the browser and another one created using the cli
2. I always create the codespace from blank template
3. I always choose the 4GB ram 2CPU option